# why wont my ps4 controller connect to my ps4 after resetting ps4

Tags: ps4, controllers

I sent my ps4 to Sony they factory reset it but now my controllers wont connect I've tried everything and I'm getting really pissed off.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the controller itself.  There is a small pin hole on the back next to the L2 trigger.  Hold it down for 3-5 seconds with a paperclip or small screwdriver, then plug it in with the USB cable and press the PS button and see if it will sync then.  [Source](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/hardware/ps4-dualshock-4-wireless-troubleshooting/)